# cartopy North Pole Stereographic contour plot does not plot correctly even with cyclic point

Tags: python, map-projections, cartopy

I am trying to plot contours over the north pole, using cartopy. I have used add_cyclic_point and this has successfully filled in the gap at the prime meridian in pcolormesh, but the contours do not cross successfully, and instead wrap all the way around the globe to connect (but it seems not always?) My longitudes go from 0-360 and I have tried to switch to -180-180 but still get the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point as cycpt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


date = '2018_02_10'
pdatafile = Dataset(date+'_mslp.nc')
plat = np.array(pdatafile.variables['lat'])
plon = np.array(pdatafile.variables['lon'])
p = np.array(pdatafile.variables['slp'][0,:,:])

p_cyclic,lon_cyclic = cycpt(p,coord=plon)
lon_cyclic = np.ma.getdata(lon_cyclic)

plon2d,plat2d= np.meshgrid(lon_cyclic,plat)
p_cyclic = np.ma.getdata(p_cyclic)

g1000datafile = Dataset(date+'_1000mb_gph.nc')
g1lat = np.array(g1000datafile.variables['lat'])
g1lon = np.array(g1000datafile.variables['lon'])
g1000 = np.array(g1000datafile.variables['hgt'][0,0,:,:])
g1_cyclic,g1lon_cyclic = cycpt(g1000,coord=g1lon)
g1lon2d,g1lat2d= np.meshgrid(g1lon_cyclic,g1lat)
g1lon2d = np.ma.getdata(g1lon2d)
g1_cyclic = np.ma.getdata(g1_cyclic)

g500datafile = Dataset(date+'_500mb_gph.nc')
g5lat = np.array(g500datafile.variables['lat'])
g5lon = np.array(g500datafile.variables['lon'])
g500 = np.array(g500datafile.variables['hgt'][0,0,:,:])
g5_cyclic,g5lon_cyclic = cycpt(g500,coord=g5lon)
g5lon2d,g5lat2d= np.meshgrid(g5lon_cyclic,g5lat)
g5lon2d = np.ma.getdata(g5lon2d)
g5_cyclic = np.ma.getdata(g5_cyclic)

thickness = g5_cyclic - g1_cyclic

mslplevels=[960,970,980,990,1000,1010,1020,1030,1040,1050]
levels500hPa = [470,480,490,500,510,520,530,540,550,560]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0))
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 50, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.pcolormesh(plon2d,plat2d,thickness/10, transform=ccrs.PlateCarre(),cmap='inferno')
cbar=plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('ReTop (gpdam)')
cs=plt.contour(plon2d,plat2d,g5_cyclic/10,colors='w',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),\
           levels=levels500hPa)
plt.clabel(cs,inline=1,fontsize=6,fmt='%3.0f')
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[an example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RImUf.png)

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point as cycpt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pdatafile = Dataset('X158.39.88.89.59.7.59.32.nc')
plat = np.array(pdatafile.variables['lat'])
plon = np.array(pdatafile.variables['lon'])
p = np.array(pdatafile.variables['slp'][0,:,:])

p_cyclic,lon_cyclic = cycpt(p,coord=plon)
lon_cyclic = np.ma.getdata(lon_cyclic)
p_cyclic = np.ma.getdata(p_cyclic)

plon2d,plat2d= np.meshgrid(lon_cyclic,plat)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0))
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 50, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.contour(plon2d,plat2d,g5_cyclic/10,colors='w',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.clabel(cs,inline=1,fontsize=6,fmt='%3.0f')
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Public/www/X158.39.88.89.59.7.59.32.nc

Comment: Your second example does not work, the file you provided doesn't contain the requested variable and there are multiple undefined variables in the code (e.g. `g5_cyclic`, `cs`).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is to do with contour labels, which are known not to work well in Cartopy (see https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/13 and https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/327). If you remove the labels the contours should render correctly.

Comment: oh my goodness, you're right it works without labels. I'm confused by that post though, it seems like they are saying that there's a solution, to label the patches instead of the lines but I'm confused as to where they are doing that?

Comment: I don't believe this is currently solved. The suggestion in the issue only relates to the specific example in question, it isn't a general fix I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a cartopy developer and I'd like to see what I can do, but your code snippet is a little bit impenetrable.  If I could access your data then it might not matter so much, but I can't, so I can't run it or debug it.

Can you cut down your script please to something self-contained or at least minimal, noiseless and clear.  Thanks.

Also you have a typo in your plot call so your transform is PlateCarre instead of Platecarree.  I don't know how much difference this will make but it's worth correcting.

Comment: thank you, i've editted my post to include a simpler version of the code, as well as a link to an example datafile. does that work?